# Add CSS class for low stock products on single product page in WooCommerce

Tags: php, css, wordpress, woocommerce, product

I am not very familiar with php, and I am trying to add a class to 'Low stock' in the snippet below.

What I am trying to achieve is making the Low Stock orange vis CSS in WooCommerce.

---

```php
function change_stock_text( $availability, $_product ) {

    if ( $_product->is_in_stock() ) {

        if ( $_product->get_stock_quantity() < 3 ) {

            $qty                          = $_product->get_stock_quantity();
            $availability['availability'] = __( "Low stock", 'woocommerce' );
        }
    }

    return $availability;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

- `add_filter()` is missing
- `$availability` contains `[availability]` & `[class]`, you change the text, while you want to add a class
- `$qty` is unused in your code
- A class doesn't have to be translatable, so using `__()` is not necessary

To add a class to the already existing class with the if condition, use the `woocommerce_get_availability_class` filter hook instead

```php
// Availability class
function filter_woocommerce_get_availability_class( $class, $product ) {
    // In stock
    if ( $product->is_in_stock() ) {
        // Stock quantity less then 3
        if ( $product->get_stock_quantity() < 3 ) {
            $class .= ' low-stock';
        }
    }

    return $class;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_availability_class', 'filter_woocommerce_get_availability_class', 10, 2 );
```

Answer (score 0):

it's been sometime since I worked with WooCommerce, so i am not sure if this will do the trick, but you can try:

```
$availability['availability'] = __( "<em class='low_stock'>Low stock</em>", 'woocommerce' );
```

This might work, otherwise there's likely a hook for it.